# What to do to solve in a React app : Charset declaration is missing or occurs too late in the HTML

Tags: html, reactjs, lighthouse

The lighthouse analysis shows me that the Charset declaration is missing or occurs too late in the HTML. but in the index.html file, I have the  element as the first element in the . What can be the reason for this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="Teacher management system for teachers in schools to manage their classrooms">
    <meta name="keywords" content="teacher, classroom, school, teacher management, school management, classroom management">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#f3d9fa">
    <!-- Title -->
    <title>ClassRoom</title>
    <!-- Icon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/icon.ico">
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;0,1000;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900;1,1000&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me and testing this page in Lighthouse does not show this error.

Comment: @BarryPollard Thank you, Barry, for testing it, 
For me, it shows the error, maybe it's from the browser.

Comment: Make sure it's in the source HTML and not added by JavaScript after load. Or that it's actually complaining about the main HTML and not an iframe or such like.

Comment: @BarryPollard What can I do for example to make sure, because the lighthouse result didn't give details